# keeping all UI logic out of ViewModel?

Tags: view, windows-8, model, viewmodel, mvvm-light

I am quite new to MVVM and i'm curious as to of it's possible to keep all UI specific things out of the ViewModel and therefore making my viewmodel portable across projects?  For example, say i want to later port my Application to windows 8 from windows phone 8.  I could easily drag over my viewmodel and model, and then design a new view which connects to the viewmodel.  If so what are some practices i should be aware of in order to make my viewmodel as portable and as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than dragging your model and VM around, you could build them into assemblies of their own and just re-use the assembly/ies in multiple projects.

It's entirely possible to separate your VM from your view by implementing [`IPropertyNotifyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). This way your VM's properties can check if they're being changed and can notify subscribers to the `PropertyChanged` event that something's changed. This way, your view can subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event on your object and can take action when it needs to update the UI to reflect the changed value of one or more properties of your object.

Be sure to work through the sample at the end of the [`IPropertyNotifyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) docs which illustrates how this works.

Comment: Richard,

Could you please throw together a quick solution that seperates the view, model, and view model.  I have tried such with NO LUCK.  My program runs perfect when my models are seperated, but when i seperate the viewmodel from the view, visual studio will compile it fine, but when i select debug, and the application begins to install on my windows phone, it fails to load and tells me the debugger failed to connected to "some local ip address of phone".  i worked with this for 6 hours yesterday and i finally gave up and just kept my viewmodels with my view and it works fine.  Thanks